# How to hide the nginx proxy sit between client and real server?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx proxy sit between client and real web server.The problem is I want to hide the nginx proxy from web server. Make the web server believe the request come from a client directly.

I can't find any posts on this problem.